# Puzzle on encoding of a word

Tags: wordplay, cipher, crosswords

In a certain code, **AFZALPUR** is written as **BCBGYVOS**

What is the code for **FARIDKOT**?

As per my attempts so far, I cannot find a definite sequence of encoding. Both A and Z appear to be encoded to B, which is a bit puzzling. Some intuition in this regard would help.

Comment: are there more examples available? just one example isn't enough to confirm a definite pattern, few more examples to test it would be helpful..

Comment: True. I found this while solving aptitude questions asked by an organization in its recruitment tests. So, this was the exact question they had asked.

Comment: So obviously, this is not a one-to-one substitutio cipher. All words have eight letters, so perhaps there are letter pairs involved? Anyway, just one example is not enough to confrm apettern. For example, you might conclude that the encryption is a Vigenère cipher with the password BXCGNGUB, which would yield GXTOQQIU for FARIDKOT, but I doubt that this is the intended answer.

Comment: Just to note that both Afzalpur and Faridkot are cities in India.

Comment: @LumosMaxima Just to clear things up, this questions is not yours right? If so, then please cite the source in your questions.